# Difference between Hmisc wtd.var and SAS proc Mean generated weighted variance

Tags: r, sas, hmisc

I'm getting different results from R and SAS when I try to calculate a weighted variance.  Does anyone know what might be causing this difference?

I create vectors of weights and values and I then calculate the weighted variance using the 
Hmisc library wtd.var function:

```
library(Hmisc)
wt <- c(5,  5,  4,  1)
x <- c(3.7,3.3,3.5,2.8)
wtd.var(x,weights=wt)
```

I get an answer of:

```
[1] 0.0612381
```

But if I try to reproduce these results in SAS I get a quite different result:

```
data test;
  input wt x;
cards;
5 3.7
5 3.3
4 3.5
1 2.8
;
run;
proc means data=test var;
var x;
weight wt;
run;
```

Results in an answer of

```
0.2857778
```

Comment: Ask SAS to post its code. `Hmisc::wtd.var` is readily available.

Comment: SAS makes nearly all of its statistical computations available (not in code-as-in-java/c++, but in mathematical form), including the variance calculation (as answered).  Asking them for source code is rather silly, unless you're going to ask Microsoft for the source code to Windows 7 and expect them to say yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a difference in how the variance is calculated.  SAS gives you an option, `VARDEF`, which may help here.

```
proc means data=test var vardef=WDF;
var x;
weight wt;
run;
```

That on your dataset gives a variance similar to `r`.  Both are 'right', depending on how you choose to calculate the weighted variance.  (At my shop we calculate it a third way, of course...)

Complete text from [PROC MEANS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm):

> VARDEF=divisor specifies the divisor to use in the calculation of the
>   variance and standard deviation. The following table shows the
>   possible values for divisor and associated divisors.

```
Possible Values for VARDEF=
Value            Divisor                     Formula for Divisor
DF               degrees of freedom          n - 1
N                number of observations      n
WDF              sum of weights minus one    ([Sigma]iwi) - 1
WEIGHT | WGT     sum of weights              [Sigma]iwi
```

> The procedure computes the variance as  `CSS/Divisor`, where  CSS
>   is the corrected sums of squares and equals  Sum((Xi-Xbar)^2). When you
>   weight the analysis variables,  CSS equals  sum(Wi*(Xi-Xwbar)^2), where 
>   Xwbar is the weighted mean.
>
> Default:   DF Requirement:     To compute the standard error of the mean,
>   confidence limits for the mean, or the Student's t-test, use the
>   default value of VARDEF=.
>
> Tip:   When you use the WEIGHT statement and
>   VARDEF=DF, the variance is an estimate of  Sigma^2, where the
>   variance of the ith observation is  Sigma^2/wi and  wi is the
>   weight for the ith observation. This method yields an estimate of the
>   variance of an observation with unit weight.
>
> Tip:   When you use the
>   WEIGHT statement and VARDEF=WGT, the computed variance is
>   asymptotically (for large n) an estimate of  Sigma^2/wbar, where 
>   wbar is the average weight. This method yields an asymptotic
>   estimate of the variance of an observation with average weight.

Comment: Thanks.  Another problem in my root issue (rather than the toy example I gave) was that I was using frequency weights rather than analytic weights.  I didn't realize SAS had a separate command for that.  So using either vardef=WDF OR replacing weights wt with freq wt2 corrected my issue.